# Jekyll SystemStackErorr "stack level too deep" on serve with github pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I can't serve a jekyll site locally and I get notified that there is a problem with GitHub pages when I commit to GitHub.

```
bundle exec jekyll -v                                         11:28:34
jekyll 3.7.3

ruby --version                                                11:28:42
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]
```

When I run:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

will fail and spit out hundreds (more like thousnads) of error messages starting with:

```
bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/usr/local/bin/jekyll)
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/base.rb:106:in `new'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/base.rb:106:in `add_text'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/html.rb:171:in `parse_raw_html'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/html.rb:60:in `handle_kramdown_html_tag'
```

From what I could tell, this can sometimes happen if you use `jekyll serve` as opposed to `bundle exec jekyll serve` and if there is a mismatch between your version of jekyll and the one required by github pages, but here I do use `bundle exec` and so the correct version of jekyll is used.

jekyll itself works if i try to create a new site with `jekyll new blah` and i can serve that one locally without a problem, but the combo of jekyll and github pages is giving me grief.

I am puzzled and do not know how to proceed.

All this is on Mac OS X 10.13.6.

Comment: This seems to be a parsing problem with kramdown. A code repository url can be useful to debug.

Comment: Update question with the contents of `/Gemfile`

Comment: Thanks, guys. The problem turned out to be something else. kramdown was choking up on a particularly large and complex file —  which didn't really need to be publicly accessible at all. Once I removed it, it was all fine. Is there a way to delete this question? I don't think it will serve any purpose here.

Answer (score 0):

Not relating to the original cause of the problem here, but i stumbled upon this and had the error `stack level too deep`. So i guess this might help someone.

I traced my problem to a field that i named as `max` in some yaml dictionary in the front matter. Maybe you have named a field which has a special meaning in `jekyll`.